# Alternative to InAppSettingsKit

Tags: iphone, ios, inappsettingskit

Is there an alternative to [InAppSettingsKit](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/) that is simpler? I find myself needing only 20% of what it offers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about [ESCOZ's QuickDialog library](http://escoz.com/open-source/quickdialog)? Seems like a reasonable alternative.

Comment: @EduardoScoz it is not maintained anymore.

Comment: @haifengkao yeah, this is a super old project now. :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, one alternative is to just build your own settings panel with a regular UIViewController and some buttons and switches, etc. and then save the settings using NSUserDefaults, e.g.

```
- (IBAction)mySettingSwitchAction:(UISwitch *)theSwitch
{
    //save the switch setting
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:theSwitch.on forKey:@"myPreferenceName"];
}
```

then you can load it again anywhere in your app using

```
BOOL theValueISet = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"myPreferenceName"];
```

Values you set in NSUserDefaults are persistent so if the app is closed and opened again they retain their values. You can call `synchronize` on NSUserDefaults to force it to save/load the values but this happens automatically on app open/close anyway.